# java FileReader, Read text Line by Line

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, filereader

I have two classes. First, the class TEXT: Here I read a text file with 6 lines. I only want to read line by line, but this works. but I want to start from the third line and also skipo the last one, I only want that the lines which start with

Here is textfile code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ICONS ERROR="false" USERNAME="WAZ" FORMAT="FLAT" RECORDS="3">
<icon ID="55"  NAM="A" />
<icon ID="87"  NAM="B" />
<icon ID="53"  NAM="C" />
</ICONS>
```

and here is the code from the filereader:

```
    package packagechain;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

   public class Text {

     String fileName;
     FileReader fr;
     BufferedReader in;
     Stream<String> lines;
     Iterator<String> l;
     boolean hasLine;

    public Text() throws FileNotFoundException{
         fileName = "E:/test30.xml";
         fr = new FileReader(fileName);
         in = new BufferedReader(fr);   
         lines = in.lines();
         l = lines.iterator();
         hasLine = true;
    }

    public String nextline() {
        String nl;

        if(l.hasNext()) {
            nl = l.next();
            //System.out.println(""+nl);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No new line!");
            hasLine = false;
            nl=null;
        }
        return nl;
    }
    }
```

and here is the code where i can edit my string which i want from the textfile , i use "substring" and this works. but if it comes to the last line where it is no value at the specific substring it comes to an error....

Error if i delete line 1 and 2 and the alst line in my textfile:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at packagepackagechain.test4.main(test4.java:18)"

Error if I add line 1 and two and the last one in my textfile


..

Error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at packagepackagechain.test4.main(test4.java:16)

```
and here is the code:

 package packagechain;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Text m;
          String s;

          try {
             m = new Text();
             while(m.hasLine) {
                s = m.nextline();

                String r = s.substring(10,12);

                System.out.println(r);

             }
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             System.out.println("File not found!");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Text class reads just the first line and your main class is instanciating a new Text object for each iteration. 
Your Text class could use the method lines to read all file lines and then iterates through them an prints each line.

```
package packagechain;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Text {
     String fileName;
     FileReader fr;
     BufferedReader in;
     Stream<String> lines;
     Iterator<String> l;
     boolean hasLine;

    public Text() throws FileNotFoundException{
         fileName = "....4-line.txt";
         fr = new FileReader(fileName);
         in = new BufferedReader(fr);   
         lines = in.lines();
         l = lines.iterator();
         hasLine = true;
    }

    public String nexline() {

        if(l.hasNext()) {
            String nl = l.next();
            System.out.println("Next line; "+nl);
            return nl
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No new line!");
            hasLine = false;
            return null;
        } 
    }    
}
```

Main class:

```
package packagechain;

public class MainProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Text m;
      String s;
      try {
         m = new Text();
         while(m.hasLine) {
            s = m.nexline();
            //EXAMPLE: for each line, print a substring starting from its third character
            if(s != null) System.out.println(s.substring(2));
            //Here I edit in future these Line , so it's important that i get line by line from my other class, becaus I Have to edit each line itself!
         }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File not found!");
    } 

    }
}
```

Comment: OK I test it but this give me the whole text I only want 1 Line and if it repeat the while or for loop it should get the next Line....

Comment: My question is how can i get 1 Line in my Main Program in a while loop , there i have to do several string with each line here I want the line as a Single String. and when the loop is at the end it start the loop again and then i used the secon line of my text .... so on and so on ... Do you understand what's my problem ??

Comment: Or is there any function where I can count the lines in the textfile and in my main programm i can count every loop which is passed and after every loop it gets also the next line ??

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer, hoping to understand the request. Now the method you wrote just print the line without return it, being void.I imagine you know that to obtain the String line to perform some action on it, you have to return and not only print it.

Comment: Ok thank you , but if i let it loop in my Main programm 2 times, then it should only show the first 2 lines from my text file... right ??? But with your code it shows me the whole textfile 2 times ....

Comment: Yes, the loop shows each time the lines one by one.
You need to return each line multiple time with loops?
I don't understand why you want to loop just to see a single line, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: When in your comment you say "if i let it loop in my Main programm 2 times, then it should only show the first 2 lines" you mean you want to see only the first line with the first loop and only the second line with the second loop?

Comment: Ok sorry if I wasn't clear enough. So in my main Programm i want a while loop and in this loop is the request where I "call " the method where it read the text line but not the whole text, only one line, so in the first loop i want to get the first line. Then I have to edit this first line as a string with somthing like tokenizer or something else, but this I haven't yet. ANd if it's finished with this String (MY first line in the text) then the loop starts again and then I want the second line as a string and so on and so on , Line by line .

Comment: It is very important that in my while loop I only get 1 Line and not every line from the text. Hope You understand what I mean

Comment: to test it I add so far a for loop , here is the code ` int anzahl = 2;
   for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++){
        Text m;
        try {
           m = new Text();
           while(m.hasLine) {
              m.nexline();
              //Here I edit in future these Line , so it's important that i get line by line from my other class, becaus I Have to edit each line itself!
           }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("File not found!");
      } 

      }
  }
}`

Comment: So do you understand what i mean when i test it with a loop which runs 2 times then I want only the first 2 lines of my text as a String .. overall 2 strings

Comment: When in your comment you say "if i let it loop in my Main programm 2 times, then it should only show the first 2 lines" you mean you want to see only the first line with the first loop and only the second line with the second loop? – Spock 5 mins ago           ------------------------------------------    Yes exactly this !!!!!

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to edit each single line, but for that a single loop is needed: in the loop, you retrieve a line, execute some manipulation on it, and then the loop goes to the following line, do the manipulation and so on.
If you put your edit where it now is placed the comment, then it applies to each line one by one.

Comment: The point is that you need only one loop to read each single line, and into that loop you can edit it

Comment: What does this mean ?? you mean this is so correct ??

Comment: Try the  code I posted: I've added a stupid example of editing, in which given the line of the file, it prints it without the first two characters. As you see, the editing is applied for each single line.
In the same way, you can perform each editing you need on each string in the same loop

Comment: Ok thank You very much , I think this is what i want!

Comment: Hello, I have one quation more, I edit my code above , how i used it now. all works , so I get my string line by line, but when the text file is at the end , my substring method want also to read the empty line and then  get a Error: Exception. How can I solve this problem , I also added my textfile which I use to test the programm. I want that only the lines which start with ... <icon ID...   should read, so the first two lines should be skipped and if there is the last line which start with <ICONS.. it should be finished without the error : Exception... I hope anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your program each of iteration text class object and buffer reader object are reallocated so they only return first line

```
package packagechain;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Text {


public BufferedReader getBufferReader() {

     BufferedReader in;

    String fileName = "...4-line.txt";

    FileReader fr = null;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        in = new BufferedReader(fr);



    }  
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Can't open");

    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("No new line!");
    }
    return  in;
    }
public void readLine(BufferedReader in){
    try {
 String line = in.readLine();


        System.out.println("Next line; "+line);

    catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("No new line!");
    }
 }
}
```

Second class code is:

```
package packagechain;

public class MainProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
      Text m = new Text();
      BufferedReader in=m.getBufferReader();
      m.readLine(in);

      //Here I edit in future these Line , so it's important that i get line by line from my other class, becaus I Have to edit each line itself!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok when i write the first code I get a few errors. in Line:     public void readLine(BufferReader in){ ....  error: BufferReader cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: and something is wrong with the " }" where I Have to close the clip from this line : public BufferedReader getBufferReader() {

Comment: import java.io.FileReader; use this import

Comment: Yes i already have . Are you sure that it called BUfferReader and not BufferedReader ?

Comment: no Problem but there is always an error in second class in line :     m.nextline(in);   Error is :  The method nextline(BufferedReader) is undefined for the type Text

Comment: OK i change this   m.nextline(in) to m.readLine(in) because I think this is the right method. But the result is that i Get the same as before. I get only the first line . and not line by line .

Comment: are you got answer now??